# Rendering html with render function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a word matching exercise that takes a set of inputs. The program reads the html from the input boxes. Then the html is displayed in a textarea element. When the user clicks "render html" the key words and descriptions are displayed. The html displayed by the program are the values are taken from value of the textarea element.

Expected:
When the user clicks render html the newly generated code from the text area should be rendered.

Actual:
When the user clicks render html the newly generated code is not rendered as expected.

I expect the program to render the newly generated code. For example,

1. If I click generated html.
2. Then I click add more.
3. Then I click render html.
4. Then I click add more.
5. Then I click render html.
6. Then I click render html.

I end up with multiple sections of rendered html. For example,

[image]

What I'd actually like to end up with is

[image]

The method for rendering the html is shown below.

```
function render_html(){
      textarea  = document.getElementById("generated_html_textarea");
      // Set the generate html to the value from the textarea.
      generated_html = textarea.value;
      console.log(generated_html);
      // Create a new tab.
      var new_window = window.open('');
      maincontentstyle = document.getElementById("maincontentstyle");
      rendered_html = document.createElement("div");
      rendered_html.setAttribute("id","rendered_html");
      rendered_html.setAttribute("style","border: 1px solid #EB0D1B; width: 360px; font-family: courier; font-size: 100.5%; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px; text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;");
      rendered_html.innerHTML +=  generated_html;
      rendered_html.innerHTML +='<span style="padding: 3px"> <button id ="one" class="button" type="button" onClick="show_answer()">Show Answer</button> <button id = "resetButton" class="button" type="button" onClick="reset()">Reset</button> </span>';
      results = document.getElementById("results");
      // Append the rendered html to the results tab
      results.appendChild(rendered_html);
      htmlRendered = true;
      header = '<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n\t<head>\n\t\t<title>Word Matching Exercise</title>\n\t\t<style>\n*:focus {outline: 2px solid blue; outline-offset: 2px;}\n\t\tdetails {padding:3px;}\n\t\t</style>\n\t\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/boxes.css\" />\n\t\t<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"event1.js?v=9999\">';
      header += '</'
      header += 'script>\n<script async src=\"https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-89940905-27\">'
      header += '</'
      header += 'script>\n<script>\n\t window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];\n\t function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};\tgtag(\"js\", new Date());\tgtag(\"config\", \"UA-89940905-27\");\n'
      header += '</'
      header += 'script>\n'
      header += '<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">'
      header += '</'
      header += 'script>'
      header += '<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery-ui.min.js">'
      header += '</'
      header += 'script>'
      header += '<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js">'
      header += '</'
      header += 'script>'
      header += '<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery.alerts.js">'
      header += '</'
      header += 'script>'
      header += '<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">'
      header += '<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/logging.js\">'
      header += '</'
      header += 'script>\n</head>\n\t\t<body>';
      new_tab_html = header;
      new_tab_html += rendered_html.innerHTML;
      footer = '\n\t\t</body>\n</html>\n';
      footer += '<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/GetElementPosition.3.js">'
      footer += '</'
      footer += 'script>'
      footer += '<script>audioOn = false; $(function() {$(\'.menulink\').click(function(){if (audioOn) {$("#bg").attr(\'src\',\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/images/audioOff.png\");  audioOn = false;}else {$(\"#bg\").attr(\'src\',"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/images/audioOn.png");audioOn = true; speak(" ");}return false;});});'
      footer += '</'
      footer += 'script>'
      footer += '<img id="bg" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/images/audioOff.png" height="30" width="30" style="margin-bottom:-10px; padding-bottom:-20px;">'
      new_tab_html += footer;
      console.log(new_tab_html);
      new_window.document.write(new_tab_html);
    }
```

I updated the function. The only issue is that when I call the method twice it renders the html twice. There needs to be some type of control that prevents the html from being rendered twice.

The github repo for the project is [here](https://github.com/EvanGertis/Selected-Topics/blob/main/wordMatch/Section5_3.html).

Comment: why are you using the `file:///` scheme to load javascript files??

Comment: This has to be run locally.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius how do you make the path relative?